# String concatenation of key in map with variable in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, string

So I have this angularjs code in my html where I am trying to access the value of a key/value pair like so:

`<td>{{ mapA.[stringX. + mapB.keyC + .stringY]}}</td>`

The value of `mapB.keyC` should concatenated to the String key to get the value of a particular key/value pair, so that the name of the key for example would be something like `stringX.valueC.stringY` to return the value of the map

How would I do this in angularjs and/or in pure javascript?

EDIT: 
I tried to be general,  however in my case I have a credit meter with a particular local currency as within its name e.g. `"credit.in.cash.GBP.2000"` and I want to get the value of it with:

`{{ meter.[credit.in.cash. + localCurrency.ISO_CODE + .2000] / 100 | currency : localCurrency.SYMBOL : 2 }}`

expected e.g.  £2000

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results. Hard to follow exactly what you need from syntax used

Comment: wouldn't it be `mapA[stringX + '.' + mapB.keyC + '.' + stringY]`?  Or maybe:  `mapA['stringX.' + mapB.keyC + '.stringY']` -- It's hard to tell from your post.

Comment: what is `meter`? Still not providing enough details because your syntax is a mess . Also remove `dot` preceding `[]` ... you use one or the other. Can not use `dot` when keyName starts with number either